# return extra columns based on group and count results

Tags: sql, group-by, duplicates

Source data:

```
+-----+-------------+--------+---------+
| ID  | CandidateID | Rating |  Name   |
+-----+-------------+--------+---------+
| 777 |         119 |      5 | Fred    |
| 777 |         120 |      5 | Tony    |
| 777 |         121 |      3 | Ben     |
| 888 |         131 |      4 | Joe     |
| 888 |         132 |      4 | Matt    |
| 888 |         133 |      1 | Russell |
+-----+-------------+--------+---------+
```

I need to find duplicates (where ID and Rating are the same), but also somehow keep a reference to them (CandidateID) to present their names in the resulting table. 
Desired output (only shows rows where ID AND Rating are the same):

```
+-----+-------------+--------+------+
| ID  | CandidateID | Rating | Name |
+-----+-------------+--------+------+
| 777 |         119 |      5 | Fred |
| 777 |         120 |      5 | Tony |
| 888 |         131 |      4 | Joe  |
| 888 |         132 |      4 | Matt |
+-----+-------------+--------+------+
```

My initial approach was to GROUP by ID and Rating, producing COUNT, then do HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2, and then listing all rows where ID from that result is present. Sadly, that also returns non-duplicate rows. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Can you post the actual query you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way uses `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.id = t.id and t2.rating = t.rating and
                    t2.candidateid <> t.candidateid
             );
```

Comment: Excellent solution. Would you care to suggest how I could use it if my table t is actually a join of two tables? Should I make that join twice: first inside the main query and then inside the 'EXISTS' clause?

Comment: @TonySepia . . . The above is standard SQL.  Most databases support common table expressions (CTEs), introduced with a `with` clause.  That expression what you want very easy.

Comment: I don't argue that it's not standard SQL. I've successfully achieved what I wanted using it. My next question is whether it is effective to use it, if my table 't' is actually a join of two tables? Then I am joining twice, right? First inside the main query and then inside the 'EXISTS' clause.

Comment: @TonySepia . . . That depends on how the query is structured and the database you are using.  Different databases have different optimizers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytics function for this as well

```
SELECT ID,CANDIDATEID,RATING,NAME
FROM T
QUALIFY COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY ID,RATING)>=2
```

based on your database, you can change syntax for count(*) over. This syntax works in teradata.

Comment: So, this is Teradata syntax?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiuyes